# Prove that the space of coefficients of convergent sequences in a Banach space is a Banach space.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, complete-spaces

came across this problem in a book I'm reading:

Let $\mathbb{X}$ be a Banach space. For a sequence of nonzero vectors $(x_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ in $\mathbb{X}$, define $\mathbb{E}:=\{a=(a_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}:\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_kx_k \text{ converges in }\mathbb{X}\}$ and $||a||_{\mathbb{E}}:=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}||\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kx_k||$. Prove that $\mathbb{E}$ is a Banach space.

I am completely stuck, so much so that I don't even know where to begin. I know that the usual proof of completeness of a space relies on translating everything to the reals and using the property that reals are complete, but I don't even know how to do that here. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How would such a proof start?

Comment: First prove that $E$ is a vector space, which amounts to showing that $E$ is closed under addition an scalar multiplication. Then show that $E$ is closed, which will imply that $E$ is complete.

Comment: @Kakashi closed in which sense? “Closed” refers to some ambient space in which $\mathbb E$ is contained.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez That means that every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{E}$ converges in $\mathbb{E}$. I tried taking a Cauchy sequence $(b_k)$ in $\mathbb{E}$ and looking at $||b_m-b_l||$ as $m,l\rightarrow\infty$, which goes to $0$. It didn't help.

Comment: @LorenzoPompili Yeah it's an important step. Based on the norm on $E$, $E$ is isomorphic to the subspace $\{(\sum_{j = 1}^{n}a_jx_j)_{n = 1}^{\infty} : \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}a_jx_j \text{ converges}\}$ of $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{N}; X)$.

Comment: @DDomjosa a sequence has to be denoted differently, e.g., as $b^{(j)}$, since the lower index is already used for the components of a single sequence. So, assume you have a Cauchy sequence $(b^{(j)})_{j\geq 0}$ in $\mathbb E$. Can you show, for instance, that it converges pointwise? That is, for fixed $k$, can you show that $b^{(j)}_k$ converges to some real number $b_k$ as $j\to\infty$, using the fact that $b^{(j)}$ is Cauchy?

Comment: @Kakashi maybe you are right, but I think it becomes confusing. In this case, I think the most natural way of showing that the space is Banach is to take a Cauchy sequence and show that it converges

Comment: Your title should say *series* rather than *sequences*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\def\ne{\mathbb E}$$
To sum up my comments and give you some more elements. Consider a Cauchy sequence $b^{(j)}$ in $\mathbb E$. Then, $\|b^{(j)}-b^{(l)}\|_\ne$ goes to zero for large $j,l$. For every $n$, one has
$$\|\sum_{k=1}^n(b^{(j)}_k-b^{(l)}_k)x_k\|\leq \|b^{(j)}-b^{(l)}\|_\ne.$$
Considering two consecutive numbers $n-1$ and $n$, using the triangular inequality, one obtains

$$|b^{(j)}_n-b^{(j)}_n|\|x_n\|=\|\sum_{k=1}^n(b^{(j)}_k-b^{(l)}_k)x_k -\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(b^{(j)}_k-b^{(l)}_k)x_k \|\leq$$
$$\leq \|\sum_{k=1}^n(b^{(j)}_k-b^{(l)}_k)x_k\| +\|\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(b^{(j)}_k-b^{(l)}_k)x_k \|\leq 2 \|b^{(j)}-b^{(l)}\|_\ne.$$
Since $b^{(j)}$ is a Cauchy sequence, this shows that also $b^{(j)}_n$ is a Cauchy sequence for every $n$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: The question is lacking context. Please read: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this post

Comment: @LorenzoPompili So, since $b_n^{(j)}$ is a Cauchy sequence of the reals, it converges to some real number $b_n$. So, all in all, the sequence $b^{(j)}$ converges to an element $b=(b_1, b_2,\ldots)\in\mathbb{E}$ pointwise. Then we just show that it converges to that element uniformly with respect to the norm $||\cdot||_{\mathbb{E}}$, which isn't hard just by using the triangle inequality, right? Thank you!!!

Comment: @DDomjosa you also need to show that the new sequence $b$ is indeed in $\mathbb E$, I don’t think it’s that immediate

Comment: @LorenzoPompili True. Would it suffice to say that $b$ is a pointwise limit of elements in $\mathbb{E}$, hence it is in $\mathbb{E}$? Probably not, since you can have a sequence of rationals that doesn't converge to a rational. I guess we would have to prove that $\mathbb{E}$ is a Banach space, but then that's the exercise... I have no idea.

Comment: We have done one step. We have shown that a Cauchy sequence has a pointwise limit, now you need to show two things: that the limit sequence $b$ belongs to $\mathbb E$ and that $b^{(j)}$ converges to $b$ in $\mathbb E$. How would you start proving that $b\in\mathbb E$? “Consider the series $\sum_n b_k x_k$, we need to show that it converges in $\mathbb X$. We know that $b^{(j)}$ converges to $b$ pointwise and $b^{(j)}$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb E$…”. Or you can proceed randomly, showing that $\|b\|_{\mathbb E}<\infty$, and that $\|b^{(j)}-b\|_{\mathbb E}\to 0$, and see what you can do from there.

Comment: There is a number of things you can attempt to do now. If you are stuck on a specific point, that is a topic for a new post. Next time you post something on this website, please make sure to include your own attempted solutions: in most cases there is always a way to start (e.g. in your case “consider a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb E$…”), and it is important to show what is the precise point where you are stuck. If you are really clueless about how to start with the problem, make sure to include the relevant definitions and the tools you think might help solving the problem.